# Text Alignment in UILabel in swift

Tags: swift, uitextview

I have a string that has English and persian words ; so I want to set persian paragraph alignment as RTL and english paragraph alignment as LTR. I  use this code for text alignment but it doesn't align each paragraph based on language and it just check the first word of text and align it RTL or LTR!

for exaple : 
I want to set text like this:
[sample image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKn82.jpg)
but this is my result:
[sample image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8Xvr.jpg)

```
extension String {
    func naturalTextAligment() -> NSTextAlignment {
        let tagschemes = [NSLinguisticTagScheme.language]
        let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: tagschemes, options: 0)
        tagger.string = self as String
        let language = tagger.tag(at: 0, scheme: .language, tokenRange: nil, sentenceRange: nil)        
        var alignment: NSTextAlignment = .natural        
        if language == nil {
            return alignment
        }        
        let direction = NSLocale.characterDirection(forLanguage: language.map { $0.rawValue } ?? "")        
        switch direction {
        case .leftToRight:
            alignment = .left
        case .rightToLeft:
            alignment = .right
        default:
            alignment = .natural
        }

        return alignment
    }
```

Comment: you need two labels for this. One label can just have one alignment.

Comment: try this u will get the desire output:

//FOR RIGHT TO LEFT
 UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft

//FOR LEFT TO RIGHT
 UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight

Answer (score 0):

I'm using my working solution after set text:

```
extension UILabel {
    func decideTextDirection () {
        let tagScheme = [NSLinguisticTagScheme.language]
        let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: tagScheme, options: 0)
        tagger.string = self.text
        let lang = tagger.tag(at: 0, scheme: NSLinguisticTagScheme.language, tokenRange: nil, sentenceRange: nil)
        let langDir = NSLocale.characterDirection(forLanguage: lang?.rawValue ?? "en")
        if langDir == .rightToLeft { self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right }
        else { self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
nameLabel.text = "مریم"
nameLabel.decideTextDirection()
```